# Problem of minimum in physics.

Tags: calculus, physics

[image]

It is necessary to go from a point $A(0,0)$ to a point $B(a,b)$ walking from A to $P(x,0)$ with a speed $v_1$ and then until the point B with a speed $v_2$.

Find where is the point in which it is necessary to abandon x axis in order to have the minimum time to complete the path.

I've called $x$ the distance of A from P.
The function is $$t(x)=\frac{x}{v_1}+\frac{\sqrt{(a-x)^2+b^2}}{v_2}$$
$$\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{v_1}+\frac{(a-x)*(-1)}{v_2* \sqrt{(a-x)^2+b^2}}=0 \Rightarrow v_2*\sqrt{(a-x)^2+b^2}=v_1*(a-x) \Rightarrow x^2(v_2^2-v_1^2)+x(-2av_2^2+2av_1^2)+(a^2v_2^2+b^2v_2^2-v_1^2a^2)=0$$

The solutions of this equation are $x_{1/2}  =a \pm \frac{v_2 b}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}  $
Putting $\frac{dt}{dx}>0$ it is verified for $0<x<a - \frac{v_2 b}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}$ and for $x>a + \frac{v_2 b}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}$.

So the minimum point is for $a + \frac{v_2 b}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}$
and  the minimum time is

$$t(a + \frac{v_2 b}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}})= \frac{b (v_1^2+v_2^2)}{v_1v_2 \sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}+\frac{a}{v_1}$$

I'm not sure that I haven't done mistakes, because in the solution on the book it indicates
$a  - \frac{v_2 b}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}  $  as the solution of minimum.

and  the minimum time

$$t(a - \frac{v_2 b}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}})= \frac{b\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}{v_1v_2}+\frac{a}{v_1}$$

but, in particular , it distinguishes the case of $\frac{v_2^2}{v_1^2}\ge \frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}$
in which the minimum time is possible walking from A to B directly.

Comment: Let's just check.  What if $v_1=v_2$?  Does your solution or the book's solution make sense?  Perhaps $v_1=v_2+\epsilon$, with $\epsilon$ small.  We should expect that as $v_1\to v_2, \, P(x,0)\to P(0,0)$.

Comment: Your answer cannot be right. $x \gt a$ is not possible.

Comment: @MathLover yes, indeed but the other solution is of maximum

Comment: the condition is due to putting equal to 0 the point of minimum but it takes the solution with - that is of maximum

Comment: I am not sure you are doing first derivative test correctly. Did you take points to the left and to the right of the other solution? My suggestion will be to do the second derivative test.

Comment: $t(x=a)<t(x=0)$ so it should be 0 the minimum...

Comment: Also there needs to be a condition of $v_1 \gt v_2$ otherwise $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that
$$ \frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{1}{v_1} - \frac{a-x}{v_2 \sqrt{(a-x)^2+b^2}} \tag1$$
and that $\frac{dt}{dx} = 0$ implies
$$ v_2 \sqrt{(a-x)^2+b^2} = v_1 (a-x), \tag2$$
which (I think--I did not check your arithmetic here) implies
$$ x^2(v_2^2-v_1^2)+x(-2av_2^2+2av_1^2)+(a^2v_2^2+b^2v_2^2-v_1^2a^2) = 0. \tag3$$

But you seem to be assuming (incorrectly) that Equation $(3)$ implies Equation $(2)$.
It does not. Equation $(3)$ *does* imply
$$ v_2 \sqrt{(a-x)^2+b^2} = \pm v_1 (a-x), $$
but this is not the same thing.
Also, the region where the left side of Equation $(3)$ is positive does not correspond to the region where $\frac{dt}{dx}$ is positive.

What Equation $(3)$ gives you is two *possible* points at which $\frac{dt}{dx}$ *might* be zero. To determine which points are actual zeros, compare each of them against Equation $(2)$.
Assuming that $v_1$ and $v_2$ both are positive,
in Equation $(2)$ we see that the left side is positive and that
therefore $a - x$ must also be positive.
That is, $x < a.$ Hence of the two roots of Equation $(3)$, the only one that can be a zero of $\frac{dt}{dx}$ is the one that is less than $a,$ namely

$$ x_0 = a - \frac{v_2 b}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}. $$

To determine whether this is a local minimum or a local maximum,
you must examine the sign of $\frac{dt}{dx}$ for values of $x$
less than $x_0$ or greater than $x_0$,
**not** the values of the left-hand side of Equation $(3).$

Comment: Just a thing, I found that $a- \frac{v_2 b}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}$ is a point of maximum seeing the sign of $\frac{dt}{dx}$

Comment: Try your calculations again. You should get the value of $\frac{dt}{dx}$ from Equation $(1)$. Then the graph of $\frac{dt}{dx}$ is negative for $x < 0$, crosses the $x$ axis once as $x$ increases, and is positive everywhere to the right of the crossing. There is no maximum of $t$, only a minimum.

Comment: the graph of $t(x)$ should be decresing between the two solution of the equation nd increasing in the external intervals

Comment: this makes possible that the solution with - is a minimum, does't it?

Comment: No, no, no, no. You haven't understood this answer at all. There is **only one zero** of $\frac{dt}{dx}.$ The other "zero" you think you found is the zero of a different function which is only slightly related to $\frac{dt}{dx}.$ All your conclusions about the shape of $t(x)$ are based on incorrect information about the zeros and signs of the derivative.

Comment: I put simply the derivative >0 and <0 e solved the disequality

Comment: No, that is not what you did. You took the function $f(x)=x^2(v_2^2-v_1^2)+x(-2av_2^2+2av_1^2)+(a^2v_2^2+b^2v_2^2-v_1^2a^2)$, which **is not the derivative of $t(x)$**, and found its zeros and signs. Then you started drawing conclusions about $\frac{dt}{dx}$ as if these were also the zeros and signs of $\frac{dt}{dx}$; but they are not, and that is why your answer is different from the book's. The book is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are mostly correct, you just have to interpret the results correctly.

You have a continuous function $t : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ and hence it must attain its minimum on the compact set $[0,a]$ in some point $x_{0} \in [0,a]$.

Moreover, $t$ is differentiable on $\langle 0,a\rangle$ and if it happens that $x_0 \in \langle 0,a\rangle$ then $x_0$ is a local extremum of $t$ so in particular $t'(x_0) = 0$. Assuming $v_1 > v_2$ (if $v_1 \le v_2$, then simply $x_0 = 0$), you correctly found that the possible zeroes of $t'$ are included in $\left\{a- \frac{bv_2}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}},a+ \frac{bv_2}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}\right\}$ (as @David K pointed out, the only actual zero of $t'$ is $a- \frac{bv_2}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}$ but it doesn't matter here). Therefore, we conclude that $$x_0 \in \left\{0,a, a-\frac{bv_2}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}},a+\frac{bv_2}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}\right\}.$$
However, we are interested only in $x_0 \in [0,a]$. Notice that $a+\frac{bv_2}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}} > a$ so this option is certainly wrong.

Moreover, we have
$$a-\frac{bv_2}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}} \in [0,a] \iff \frac{bv_2}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}} \le a \iff \frac{v_2}{v_1} \le \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$

Hence if $\frac{v_2}{v_1} \le \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, then $a-\frac{bv_2}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}} \in [0,a]$ and this is indeed the minimum point. Namely,

$$t\left(a-\frac{bv_2}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}\right) = \frac{a}{v_1}+\frac{b\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}{v_1v_2}$$
which is smaller than both $t(0)$ and $t(a)$. We can use Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$\frac{a}{v_1}+\frac{b\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}{v_1v_2}\le \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{v_1^2}+\frac{v_1^2-v_2^2}{v_2^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{v_2} = t(0),$$
$$\frac{a}{v_1}+\frac{b}{v_2} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}{v_1}}_{\le 1} \le \frac{a}{v_1}+\frac{b}{v_2} = t(a).$$

On the other hand, if $\frac{v_2}{v_1} > \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, then this point is not in $[0,a]$ so it has to be simply $x_0 = 0$ or $x_0 = a$. It is not hard to see that
$$t(0) \le t(a) \iff \frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{v_2} \le \frac{a}{v_1}+\frac{b}{v_2} \iff \frac{v_2}{v_1} \ge \frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-b}a$$
and the latter is true in our case since
$$\frac{v_2}{v_1} > \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \ge  \frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-b}a.$$
So it has to be $x_0 = 0$.

Therefore:

$$x_0 = \begin{cases}
a-\frac{bv_2}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}, &\text{ if } \frac{v_2}{v_1} \in \left\langle 0, \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right] \\ 
0, &\text{ if } \frac{v_2}{v_1} \in \left[\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}, 1\right\rangle \\ 
\end{cases}$$

If $v_1 >> v_2$ then $x_0$ approaches $a$, namely
$$\lim_{\frac{v_2}{v_1} \to 0} \left(a-\frac{bv_2}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}\right) = \lim_{\frac{v_2}{v_1} \to 0} \left(a-\frac{b}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{v_1}{v_2}\right)^2-1}}\right) = a$$
but it is always faster to go at least somewhat diagonally than straight left and then straight up.

On the other hand, if $v_1$ approaches $v_2$ then you may wonder why
$$\lim_{\frac{v_2}{v_1} \to 1} \left(a-\frac{bv_2}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}\right) = -\infty$$
and not $0$ but this expression stops being relevant as soon as $\frac{v_2}{v_1} \ge \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ as is it is faster to simply go diagonally.

Comment: I disagree with the statement, "you correctly found the zeroes of $t′$". There is only one zero of $t'$; the other value found in the question is a false solution.

Comment: @DavidK You are right, thanks, I edited my answer accordingly. However, I'm nowhere actually using the derivative to prove that something is a minimum, merely to find candidates which I then compare by hand. Hence it suffices to know that the possible zeroes of $t'$ are included in $a\pm \frac{bv_2}{\sqrt{v_1^2-v_2^2}}$, which OP found.

Comment: Yes, I think we're all using the same expression to get the possible zeros. My comment is merely a technical side note.